# Android project compiles and runs without module-level build.gradle. Is it right?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have got a 3 years old project (Android service) where there is only a top level (project-level) build.gradle file.

The file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    productFlavors {
        arm {
            ndk {
                abiFilters = ["armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"]
            }
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "9.99.99.99"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("myapp.jks")
            storePassword "mypwd"
            keyAlias "myalias"
            keyPassword "mykeypwd"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug{
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

All documents and tutorials I have read, including Google and Gradle official documentation, state that there should be 2 Gradle files, project-level and module-level.

My project has only one, project-level, build.gradle file, that looks like a combination of two. The project compiles and runs without any problem. So, **is the module-level build.gradle a must if the project has only one module?**

Comment: You don't have any modules, strictly speaking. A single `build.gradle` file for a module-less project is just fine.

Comment: Same thing i am facing. Can you please guide me how to resolve it with single gradle file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one does not necessarily require modules (that was common at times of Eclipse IDE with Android ADT and `ant` or `mvn`), while you could split the file at `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`and move that into a sub-directory and reference it as a module in `settings.gradle` (which became merely the standard with Android Studio).

it basically depends, if one may require further modules in a project - and while having a project with one sub-project by default, it's less effort to add and/or remove further modules, without having to mess around first. also, this can reduce build times, when not always having to rebuild the whole code-base, but only the module one has changed.

Comment: Are you saying that, if I am sure the project will never have modules, I can merge 2 build.gradle files into one, project-level?

Comment: @Flot2011 would assume this should build just alike it is. that's available: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html

Comment: Thanks for clearing that for me. I will wait a bit, to see if somebody probably has some more insights, and then will  accept.